# CrudRepository does not delete an Object with relationship

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit, junit4

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.
I have created this Repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface MenuRepository extends CrudRepository<Menu, Long> {
..
}
```

and this service class

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class MenuService {

     @Autowired
     protected MenuRepository menuRepository;

     @Transactional
     public void delete (Menu menu) {
         menuRepository.delete  (menu);
     }
     ..
}
```

and this Junit Test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={TestSystemConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MenuGestApplication.class) 
public class MenuServiceTests {
...
@Test
    public void testDelete () {

        Menu menu = new menu(); 
        menu.setmenuId("bacalla-amb-tomaquet");
        menuService.save(menu);

        MenuPrice menuPrice = new menuPrice(menu);
        menuPrice.setPrice((float)20.0);
        menuPriceService.save(menuPrice);

        MenuPriceSummary menuPriceSummary = new menuPriceSummary(menu);
        menuPriceSummary.setFortnightlyAvgPrice((float)20.0);

        menuPriceSummaryService.save(menuPriceSummary);

        menu = menuService.findBymenuId("bacalla-amb-tomaquet");

        assertNotNull (menu);

        menuService.delete (menu);

        menu = menuService.findBymenuId("bacalla-amb-tomaquet");

        assertNull (menu);

    }
}
```

But the Junit is failing because the object is not deleted and no exception is thrown !

I have this in the proerty, as suggested..

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="menu", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,  orphanRemoval = true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<MenuPrice> price;
```

even that I see this in the console when running the tests:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`elcormenu`.`t_menu_price`, CONSTRAINT `FK19d0sljpshu4g8wfhrkqj7j7w` FOREIGN KEY (`menu_id`) REFERENCES `t_menu` (`id`))
```

and the Menu class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_menu")
public class Menu  implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id;    

    @JsonProperty("MenuId")
    private String MenuId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Menu", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<MenuPrice> MenuPrice = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "Menu", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private MenuPriceSummary summary;
...
}
```

Comment: Why you are not deleting using primary key of Menu Entity ?

Comment: How does the Menu Entity look like? Expecially the id generation?

Comment: What annotation is on MenuPrice reference to Menu? @ManyToOne? Can you show the code for both entities.

Comment: Do not add a `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` on a `@ManyToOne` relationship. If you do removing a MenuPrice would attempt to delete it's Menu which would attempt to delete all it's MenuPrices. Much safer to only apply the bare minimum CascadeTypes. I would also avoid modifying the default FetchType.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining a Bidirectional relationship between Menu and MenuPrice by using both `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne`. When you have a biodirectional relationship you need to set both sides. In the test you are setting Menu in MenuPrice but not adding the MenuPrice to Menu's MenuPrice Set. Include the following statement `menu.MenuPrice.add(menuPrice);` after you create menuPrice. You also do not need multiple `save()` since you have specified `Cascade.All`. Try the following:

```
public void testDelete () {

    Menu menu = new menu(); 
    menu.setmenuId("bacalla-amb-tomaquet");

    MenuPrice menuPrice = new menuPrice(menu);
    menuPrice.setPrice((float)20.0);

    // Not needed
    // menuPriceService.save(menuPrice);

    // Add menuPrice to menu's menuPrice set
    menu.menuPrice.add(menuPrice);

    MenuPriceSummary menuPriceSummary = new menuPriceSummary(menu);
    menuPriceSummary.setFortnightlyAvgPrice((float)20.0);

    // Set menuPriceSummary in menu        
    menu.summary = menuPriceSummary;

    // Not needed
    //menuPriceSummaryService.save(menuPriceSummary);

    // Saving menu will save it children too
    menuService.save(menu);

    menu = menuService.findBymenuId("bacalla-amb-tomaquet");

    assertNotNull (menu);

    menuService.delete (menu);

    menu = menuService.findBymenuId("bacalla-amb-tomaquet");

    assertNull (menu);

}
```

In may cases, you don't need bidirectional relationships and can remove the `@OneToMany`, but this depends on how your business logic needs to navigate to the children or query it via JPA.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that in the child objects: MenuPrice, MenuPriceSummary you have `CascadeType.ALL` , something like

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="menu", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<MenuPrice> price;
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about that:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class MenuService {
```

But my main question would be: For what did you use the `@Transactional` annotation within a spring boot app?

Comment: @Transactional on delete method overwrite what is defined in class level

Comment: I've to reread the manual, but i think that @Transactional is for use with the EntityManager and not applicable to Repositories.

Edit: Okay, could be mixed

Comment: Good explanation: https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/

Comment: But here @Transactional is on service level, not Repository level

Comment: It makes more sense for `@Transactional` to be at the service level, since this where you may be making changes to more than one repository and want all the changes to succeed or rollback together.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the @Transactional(**readOnly = true**) from `MenuService`. This could prevent the flushing.

Otherwise I would try the approach of en Lopes. There are diffrent `CascadeType`:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html

Comment: The way he is using `@Transaction` is a best practice; `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` on the class and `@Transactional` on the methods that modify the database.

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler thing that worked is to add `@PreRemove` to the parent that sets the child value to `null`: My concept was an `@OneToOne` relationship where a `Registration` object has a `Subscription` object. They both had foreign key to each other.

Inside `Registration` class:

```
@PreRemove
private void preRemove() {
    setSubscription(null);
}
```